# Android WebView cannot play youtube video

Tags: android, android-webview, android-youtube-api

I try to play a youtube video in a WebView. So far the video loads but the play button still doesnt work. Embedding the video wont work for me (because many videos simply cannot be played that way because of licencing problems), neither would opening a browser/youtube/whatever. So basically my only other option would be using the Youtube Android API which I find a bit much for a simple task like that.

I checked most answers here but nothing really worked.

Here is the problem in one pic. Clicking on the play button just opens this slider with some like-dislike features, but the video never gets played.

[image]

My code is:

```
w = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
w.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
w.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {});
w.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
w.loadUrl(url);
```

Would appreciate any input regarding this